# How to insert username in VS2008(report edition)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, visual-studio-2008

I'm creating a new report (*.rdl), and there I want to add username who runs the script (insert).

I've tried on VS2008 through "built-in-fields" function which is "User ID", but it didn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE #Some_Table
(
Plan_date date null,
Plan_customer int null,
creator_id nvarchar(55) null
)

INSERT INTO Some_Table
(

[Plan_date] ,
[Plan_customer],
[creator_id]

)
SELECT
@p_plan_monthly,
@p_plan_clients,
@creator_id ="user id" --from built-in-fields
```

Expected result is: Column `creator_id` is filling with value of username from active directory who made insert through my report.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? `@creator_id ="user id"` would try set the value of `@creator_id` to the value of the **column** `user_id`. Is your dataset using stored credentials or the credentials of the user running the report?

Comment: Also, Are you really still using 2008? That has about 6 weeks left of support, so you really need to look up upgrading soon.

Comment: Dataset using stored data source with stored credentials of 'sa' user, when report will be deployed on report server, users from active directory will use for insert purpose, and i would like to store information about who did insert from ActiveDirectory.

Comment: You ***need*** to use a different account to access your data @whitefang. The `sa` account should **never** be used for something as mundane as a report. In truth it should never be used unless you really need `sysadmin` privileges, or you're doing something like recovering the server. You should have a service account that can do the respective tasks it needs to. If you can suffer injection through those reports, you're service is like an open book to whomever has access.

Comment: Thanks, will look for other options )

Comment: "It looks like an 18th camel?" What does that even mean? What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: Thanks, will look for other options )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reiterate my comment, as it's is incredibly important:
"You ***need*** to use a different account to access your data @whitefang. The `sa` account should **never** be used for something as mundane as a report. In truth it should never be used unless you really need `sysadmin` privileges, or you're doing something like recovering the server. You should have a service account that can do the respective tasks it needs to. If you can suffer injection through those reports, you're service is like an open book to whomever has access."

Now, onto your problem. I would add a further internal parameter on your report. Change the value of the parameter to have the default value of `=User!UserID`; this will be the ID of the user running the report (perhaps something like `StackOverflow\Larnu`).

Then map that report parameter to your dataset parameter `@creator_id` and change your `INSERT` statement to:

```
INSERT INTO Some_Table ([Plan_date],
                        [Plan_customer],
                        [creator_id])
VALUES (@p_plan_monthly, @p_plan_clients, @creator_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: "and there I want to add username who runs the script (insert)"

You can use these functions.

```
-- database user name
SELECT USER_NAME() 
-- login identification name
SELECT SUSER_NAME()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the OP's late comment, this won't work as they are using the `sa` account (which is a really bad idea) as the login.